# Crusader Kings II. How character`s events with is_triggered_only = yes and weight_multiplier block fire, when they doesn`t exist in on_actions events?

Tags: crusader-kings-2-modding

Question in subject.
For example:

1. I have the following character event:

   ```
   character_event = {
       id = 110004
       desc = EVTDESC110004
       picture = GFX_evt_lunatic

       min_age = 16
       capable_only = yes
       prisoner = no
       is_triggered_only = yes 

       trigger = { 
           is_alive = yes
           NOT = { 
               trait = tyrant
           }
           OR = {
               trait = wroth
               trait = deceitful
               trait = cruel
               trait = greedy
               trait = impaler
           }   
       }

       weight_multiplier = {
           factor = 1

           modifier = {
               factor = 1.7
               trait = brave
           }
           modifier = {
               factor = 0.5
               trait = craven
           }
           modifier = {
               factor = 1.1
               trait = tall
           }
           modifier = {
               factor = 1.5
               trait = cruel
           }
           modifier = {
               trait = genius
               factor = 1.5
           }
           modifier = {
               trait = quick
               factor = 1.4
           }   
           modifier = {
               trait = slow
               factor = 0.4
           }
           modifier = {
               trait = imbecile
               factor = 0.1
           }
           modifier = {
               trait = inbred
               factor = 0.4
           }
           modifier = {
               trait = strong
               factor = 1.2
           }
           modifier = {
               trait = weak
               factor = 0.6
           }       
           modifier = {
               factor = 1.85
               trait = impaler
           }
           modifier = {
               factor = 0.85
               trait = depressed
           }
           modifier = {
               factor = 1.5
               trait = wroth
           }
           modifier = {
               factor = 1.1
               trait = greedy
           }
           modifier = {
               factor = 0.9
               trait = ill
           }
           modifier = {
               factor = 0.6
               trait = infirm
           }
           modifier = {
               factor = 0.9
               trait = drunkard
           }
           modifier = {
               factor = 1.5
               trait = proud
           }
           modifier = {
               factor = 0.5
               trait = slothful
           }
       }

       option = { # tyrant
           name = EVTOPTA110004
           add_trait = tyrant
       }
   }
   ```
  ---
2. I have the following trait:

   ```
   tyrant = {
       personality = yes
       opposites = {
           kind
       }
       general_opinion = -5
       vassal_opinion = 15

       martial = 2
       intrigue = 1
       stewardship = 2
       diplomacy = -2
       learning = -1

       ai_zeal = 10
       ai_ambition = 15
       ai_greed = 5
       ai_honor = -10
   }
   ```
  ---
3. I don't have any code, that's contain `add_trait = tyrant`, except in **on_action** `character_event` with `is_triggered_only = yes` and `weight_multiplier` block, which subscribing above in first section.
  ---
4. I don't have any code, that's fires **on_action event** with `id = 110004`, which subscribing above in first section.
  ---
5. I don't have any code, that's contain **on_action trigger**, that's contain **on_action event** with `id = 110004`, which subscribing above in first section.

---

**All the same, some characters in game, including ruled by AI, have the trait tyrant. How did it happen?**

---

### Some additions

So, we talk about **character events**, which are **on_action events** without **on_action triggers**. In this context we can see following messages in log file **error.log** for this events, for example:

```
[eventmanager.cpp:739]: Triggered Only Event 110004 is not fired from anywhere!
[eventmanager.cpp:739]: Triggered Only Event 110005 is not fired from anywhere!
[eventmanager.cpp:739]: Triggered Only Event 110006 is not fired from anywhere!
[eventmanager.cpp:739]: Triggered Only Event 110007 is not fired from anywhere!
[eventmanager.cpp:739]: Triggered Only Event 110008 is not fired from anywhere!
[eventmanager.cpp:739]: Triggered Only Event 110009 is not fired from anywhere!
```

---

So, how I wrote above, for some characters, including ruled by AI, this events, all the same, are firing. Please, explain me anybody this magic.

---

### Proposal

Perheps, It was able, because **on_action events** without **on_action triggers** have default **on_action trigger**. But this conclusion didn't implicitly sudscribed anywhere, including modding docs. And in this case, can anybody help me explain, which **on_action trigger** is exactly default for events of this type?

Comment: We have no idea what game you are talking about or what tools, API or programming language you are using. If you want a chance of help I'd recommend filling that in.

Comment: Oh, Shure! In Subject Now.

Comment: It was happen, because my question was migrated yesterday from gaming.stakexchange.com and here there is nоt any tags for Crusader Kings || yet. I can`t create a new tags, because I have low reputation. If anyone can help me with this, I will be happy. Sorry for my bad English. ;)

Comment: I don't think you will find much know-how about modding specific games here. You might want to try a community which is specifically about modding your game.

Comment: Can anybody help me to make a question with link on this subject on [paradoxplaza forum](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?forums/crusader-kings-ii.551/) in sub Forum for mods?